# How to find how many seconds outside of time ranges

Tags: php, time

I need to write a script that calculated the number of seconds travelled outside a number of separate time ranges.  Take this example:

```
Shift Hours: 09:00 - 17:00
Standby Hours: 06:00 - 09:00

Travel start time: 05:00
Site arrival: 06:00
```

In the above example the script would output 3600 seconds (1 hour) as it would be calculated from 05:00 - 06:00.

**Any time travelled during standby or shift hours should not be counted.**

Another example:

```
Shift Hours: 09:00 - 17:00
Standby Hours: 06:00 - 09:00

Travel start time: 06:00
Site arrival: 08:00
```

The above example should output 0 as the time travelled 06:00 - 08:00 was travelled during standby hours.

Another example:

```
Shift Hours: 09:00 - 17:00
Standby Hours: 06:00 - 09:00

Travel start time: 06:00
Site arrival: 08:00
Site Departure: 18:00
Home time: 20:30
```

In the above example should output 9000 seconds as they left site at 18:00 and got home at 20:30 (2.5 hours).

Another example:

```
Shift Hours: 09:00 - 17:00
Standby Hours: 06:00 - 09:00

Travel start time: 06:00
Site arrival: 08:00
Site Departure: 16:00 << leaves before shift ends
Home time: 18:00
```

The above example should only output 3600 seconds because they have left site early it only counts travel from the time their shift ends, so 17:00 - 18:00.

Does anyone know how I can program the above?

Comment: If you have nothing constructive to say then please refrain from commenting at all.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using timezones and I'm already using Unix time stamps for all of the times